# Run the same bash script in multiple processes

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, parallel-processing

I have a bash script that basically translates an argument to a kubectl command. For example:
$ ./file.sh service1 (will run command kubectl logs service1- -n namespace -f)
or
$ ./file.sh service2 (will run command kubectl logs service2- -n anothernamespace -f)

My problem is that when I run it to see the logs live with option -f (follow) and I want to open another terminal tab to see the logs from another service with the same script, the first process is killed. So how can I run the same script from multiple terminals without stopping eachother and seeing the output for all.

Comment: It's unlikely that's this is an issue with running a single script in multiple terminals. I'd search for a clue somewhere else (logs, return codes ...).

Answer (score 1):

Run the program in the background and output the log to out.file

```
command >> out.file 2>&1 &
```